# How to create a property (collection) expression selector from a string?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I wanted to transform the string "*Employee.Orders.OrderID*" in the **linq expression**: "***employee.Orders.Select(order => order.OrderID)***".

I already know how to do this in simple properties such as "Employee.FirstName" my question is how to do this in properties within a type within a collection.

"Order" is a collection of orders in the class "Employee".
"OrderID" is a property of the class "Order".

In other words, I want to transform this;

```
string path = "Employee.Orders.OrderID";
```

Into this;

```
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> exp = employee => employee.Orders.Select(order => order.OrderID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

https://gist.github.com/4149424

I haven't compiled the resulting expression, but it builds the expression without an exception.

**EDIT:** I've added a line to create the lambda and compile it too, which it does, so it works.

It handles your scenario where you access a property of a collection `Orders.OrderID`, which is the part that makes it sort of complicated. Without it, it would be about 30 lines shorter.

Currently, what it does is split the string on '.' and then it recursively processes every element. If the element is `IEnumerable` (but not a string) it builds an additional `Select` lambda.

It also handles a slightly more complex (but more of the same) scenario where you access a collection property in a collection property.

Comment: I have not had time to test, but it was very good, thanks.
I'll do some testing in a few hours and come back here if it works to confirm your answer.

Comment: So I came back here to thank for your help, your answer worked perfectly.
You helped an open source project to become even better, if you or anyone wants to know more about the project look here: http://tgh.codeplex.com/

Comment: Glad I could help :) Good luck on the project! I have a similar-ish project (https://github.com/JulianR/ThisMember/wiki more similar to Automapper than your library) that does lots of stuff with expressions, hence why I knew this.